# How to change NaN values to 0 in Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I have a Chart in which I'm taking the values with AngularJS.
When there are no Values, Angular throws it as `undefined`.

And when passing these values to the Chart, the chart don't shows them (Which is fine because is the same as 0). But in the tooltip, when hover, shows the values as "Not a Number" (NaN).

[image]

How can I make it show all the NaN values as **0** (zero)?

Don't know if watching my code really helps, but here it is:

```
$scope.Chart = {
       segmentShowStroke: false,
       responsive: true,
       maintainAspectRatio: false,
       scales: {
           xAxes: [{
               stacked: true,
               ticks: {
                   autoSkip: false
               },
               gridLines: {
                   display: false
               }
           }],
           yAxes: [{
               stacked: true,
               ticks: {
                   beginAtZero: true
               },
               gridLines: {
                   display: true,
                   color: "rgb(150,150,150)"
               }
           }]
       },
       legend: {
           display: true,
           position: 'top',
           labels: {
               usePointStyle: true,
               fontColor: "white"
           }
       },
       plugins: {
           datalabels: {
               color: '#171d28',
               display: function(context) {
                   return context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex] !== 0;
               },
               anchor: 'center',
               align: 'center',
               clamp: true
           },
           deferred: {
               yOffset: '45%',
               delay: 200
           }
       }
   };
   $scope.Colors = [
       { backgroundColor: 'rgb(204,234,248)' },
       { backgroundColor: 'rgb(102,194,235)' },
       { backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,154,221)' },
       { backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,84,134)' }
   ];
   $scope.Series = ['1 - Poor', '2 - Average', '3 - Acceptable', '4 - Good'];
   $scope.Labels = ['Performance', 'Mobile Capability', 'Reporting'];
   $scope.Data = [
       [ ratingPerformance1, ratingMobileCapability1, ratingReporting1 ],
       [ ratingPerformance2, ratingMobileCapability2, ratingReporting2 ],
       [ ratingPerformance3, ratingMobileCapability3, ratingReporting3 ],
       [ ratingPerformance4, ratingMobileCapability4, ratingReporting4 ]
   ];
```

Comment: Where's the (minimal and relevant) code ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: sometimes i ask myself how such a question can be asked from another developer...at least he / she should know that having a look at the source code is much more important than any images....

Comment: @DenysSéguret Sure, I added the code of my chart!

Comment: this seems not to be all **relevant** code - or do i miss smth? where is that tooltip handler? i also cannot detect any code which could return "NaN"

Comment: @messerbill - The tooltip handler is included within the Chart.js library.

Comment: @messerbill I'm taking the values with AngularJS from a Sharepoint list, the part of `$scope.Data` are the values which I saved, each `ratingPerformance1` comes from a function in which I stored the info.. But to change the NaN value in the tooltip I need to change something in the Chart code (The one I'm showing), but I don't know how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chart.js provides hooks for you to customize the content in the tooltips. They [provide an example in their documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback) for rounding, but you can quickly modify it to show a `0` instead of `NaN`. It should roughly look like this:

```js
$scope.Chart = {
    ...
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                    label += isNaN(tooltipItem.yLabel) ? '0' : tooltipItem.yLabel;
                    return label;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! you just saved me with this little code

Answer (score 0):

> Hey, I had the same error as you and I tried to put many conditions in
>   my code but I failed then after I got my final result. And I got
>   succeed.

**My code like this**

```
  helper[key].NoOfReels += isNaN((parseFloat(o.NoOfReels)) == "" || parseFloat(o.NoOfReels));
```

**or**

```
isNaN(parseFloat(data[i].NoOfReels)) ? '0' : parseFloat(data[i].NoOfReels);
```